# How to protect JSON response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am currently developing an Online Examination web app. Where students can take part in exams online. Teachers can add exams questions, and it will be retrieved for the students. I am using Codeigniter PHP framework.

For the questions table I have it roughly like this:
[image: Questions Table]

And to retrieve that, I use an ajax call using GET method and the response will be in JSON. For the backend, I select from that table and return it using

```
json_encode()
```

This is the code:

**Client Side**

```
function getQuestions() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "exams/getQuestions",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#lblA").html(a[0]);
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    $results = $this->ExamModel->getQuestions();
    //print_r($results);

    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

**Model**

```
  public function getQuestions(){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("question");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
    else return false;    
  }
```

What I get as response is:
[image: Questions JSON response]

As you can see because in questions table I have a **right_ans** column, it also shows up. I see it as a security risk because then students would know the answers. So my questions are how would I prevent students from knowing it?

I have an idea to create one more column in **questions table** as **ans_d** and have **right_ans** column as well, but when retrieving the data, I don't select the **right_ans** column. I am still uncertain, so I appreciate all help!

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want them to know it, don't send it. Make a piece of Json that excludes this information.

Comment: just remove right answer from response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `select` and select fields that you need:

```
$this->db->select("id, question, ans_a, ans_b, ans_c");
```

In this case no one will see any other fields as they are not selected and therefore not passed to client.

Answer (score 1):

Just get all the columns except answer:

```
  $this->db->select("ans_a,ans_b,ans_c,id,question");
```